# 18.04.3 LTS: How to arrange desktop window's applications at startup

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, window

I have some desktop apps launching at startup, and want these apps to open on the second screen. How do I set a fixed position for a specific application ?

I run Ubuntu 18.04.3 stock (gdm and xorg, not wayland).

Comment: This should be possible with devilspie or devilspie2, a daemon that places windows if rules for it are defined.